# Enumerating cases(Case 1, Case 2, etc.) inside problems

Tags: cases

I am a beginner at latex and I was wondering how to enumerate cases. I tried to use `\begin{case}`, but the numbering is off. If I had multiple problems that involved cases, the numbering doesn't restart after each problem but continues on like nothing happened. How do I get this to stop. Also when I talk about cases I mean Case 1 and Case 2

Also I am using all these packages I found on sharelatex:

```
\documentclass[28pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=1.0cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{chessfss} %chess figure for HW #2
\usepackage[english]{babel} %table for problem A.43
\usepackage{multirow} %table for problem A.43 %\usepackage[table]{xcolor} color certain blocks in a table %\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}  just to show the margins \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel} \usepackage{array}  %BETWEEN TWO 2-DIGIT NUMBERS

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}} \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} \newcommand{\thedate}{\today}

\newtheoremstyle{case}{}{}{}{}{}{:}{ }{} \theoremstyle{case} \newtheorem{case}{Case}


\newenvironment{theorem}[2][Theorem]{\begin{trivlist}  \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries
#2.}]}{\end{trivlist}} \newenvironment{lemma}[2][Lemma]{\begin{trivlist} \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries
#2.}]}{\end{trivlist}} \newenvironment{exercise}[2][Exercise]{\begin{trivlist} \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries
#2.}]}{\end{trivlist}} \newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist} \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries
#2.}]}{\end{trivlist}} \newenvironment{question}[2][Question]{\begin{trivlist} \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries
#2.}]}{\end{trivlist}} \newenvironment{corollary}[2][Corollary]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
```

Comment: You should take a look at packages  which manage theorem-like structures (`amsthm`, `ntheorem`, and their extension `thmtools`.

Comment: trivlist is not intended to be nested.  Nesting uses a different counter for each level (e.g. enumi, enumii, enumiii, enumiv) depending on the \@enumdepth count register.

Comment: Is this problem essentially the same as your recent one, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384263/the-enumeration-for-the-cases-doesnt-start-back-up-at-1-when-i-start-a-new-prob?